# Oracle: How to update master with newest row from detail table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

We have two tables:

Vehicle:

- Id
- RegistrationNumber
- LastAllocationUserName
- LastAllocationDate
- LastAllocationId

Allocations:

- Id
- VehicleId
- UserName
- Date

What is the most efficient (easiest) way to update every row in Vehicle table with newest allocation? In SQL Server I would use UPDATE FROM and join every Vehicle with newest Allocation. Oracle doesn't have UPDATE FROM. How do you do it in Oracle?

** EDIT **

I am asking for best SQL query for update. I will be using trigger to update data in master table. I  know how to write trigger. All I am asking is how to write SQL query to update Vehicle table. Example would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: This would be better served by removing the offending columns from the VEHICLE table, and using a view to provide the latest allocation information.  This setup requires you to use a trigger on the ALLOCATIONS table to maintain the poor decision choice.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: View will be simply slower.

Comment: For a simple query like that? No.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: How do you know that it is that simple? LastAllocationUserName, LastAllocationDate and LastAllocationId are used in much more complicated queries. Using another view will complicate execution plan and will have to look into another table (Allocations), instead of just using values in Vehicles. Vehicle table can have thousands rows, Allocations can have tens of thousands. When combined with other joins, it affects performance.

Comment: The data model likely shouldn't have been made the way it is in the first place.  Redundant data is common in financial systems; redundant volatile data is just ugly.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ugly, but efficient. Using views is not that efficient. What other solution could you suggest, which is as fast as this redundancy? LastAllocationUserName, LastAllocationDate and LastAllocationId are accessed very frequently. Allocations are created not that often and trigger cost is not serious.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that a view is inefficient?  It's prepared SQL statement - there's nothing in an Oracle explain plan about using a view.  WHERE clause criteria (predicates) that doesn't use functions is pushed into the view query itself.  You need to compare the explain plan from the query in a view, and running the view itself for you to understand your misinterpretation.

Comment: Sorry, but are you saying that taking data directly from Vehicle table has the same efficiency as joining view and taking data from view? Joins don't cost?

Comment: I'll take that to be an admission that there is in fact nothing inherently inefficient in using views.  If joins cost so much, you'd only use one, monolithic table in a database.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I am not saying that using views is wrong, but using view to get the last row all the time is not the most efficient solution. Even if I use view, it doesn't magically store data I need, it will still have to look into Allocations table and find latest Allocation using date criteria. Even if query is compiled and parametrized, its execution has to be repeated almost every time it is used, because data change. If I have latest row stored somewhere else, access is faster. Is it really that illogical?

Comment: +1 For stating in one lower comment that the database design is not the point of this question. I don't know why we programmers tend to judge everything when it is not done the way we would do it ourselves and having that diffifulty to accept others' choices, in my opinion.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: Thanks for comment. In fact, this is not even my db design. This database was built 6-7 years ago and it is not easy to change it now. And in fact, I see nothing really wrong in storing newest row in another table. I wouldn't just place it in Vehicles, just added another NewestAllocation and filled it with proper data. if I care mostly for newest row, but still want to store history (and freely change it, not in chronogical order), what is wrong with it?

Comment: @LukLed: What do you honestly think you are implying when you state repeatedly that "views are inefficient"?  There's nothing inherently inefficient in using a view, because there's nothing to support your claim in the explain plan.  *A view is only as good as the query it encapsulates*.  Oracle supports materialized views, BTW.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I am implying that taking single row is faster that making select from view that has to scan through an index to extract data. View is as good as query, but even sql jedi will not write regular view, that is as fast as taking data from the same table. Yes, there are materialized views. That propaly could also be solution and would have good performance, but it is the first time you say `materialized`. Before you wrote about regular views.

Comment: When did you distinguish between views and materialized views in your clearly baseless efficiency claims?  Never.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You are trying to imply that you were saying about materialized views all the time? OK, thanks for help.

Comment: No, you're trying to imply that I was.  I've given you the benefit of the doubt, but it's clear you just want to troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by most others: you have a big problem due to your data model. Most code written for this model, will be much more difficult than it needs to be. I've said it by up and downvoting and in some of the comments as well, but it can't be said enough.

If you continue on your path, then the code below demonstrates what needs to be done. Hopefully it scares you :-)

The sample tables:

```
SQL> create table vehicles (id,registrationnumber,lastallocationusername,lastallocationdate,lastallocationid)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 1, 'Me', sysdate-1, 2 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 2, 'Me', sysdate, 3 from dual
  5  /

Table created.

SQL> create table allocations (id,vehicleid,username,mydate)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 1, 'Me', sysdate-2 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 1, 'Me', sysdate-1 from dual union all
  5  select 3, 2, 'Me', sysdate-1 from dual
  6  /

Table created.
```

The trigger would have to look into its own table to determine the last allocation. Oracle prevents this type of dirty reads by raising a mutating table error. To circumvent this I create a SQL type and a package:

```
SQL> create type t_vehicle_ids is table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create package allocations_mutating_table
  2  as
  3    procedure reset_vehicleids;
  4    procedure store_vehicleid (p_vehicle_id in vehicles.id%type);
  5    procedure adjust_vehicle_last_allocation;
  6  end allocations_mutating_table;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> create package body allocations_mutating_table
  2  as
  3    g_vehicle_ids t_vehicle_ids := t_vehicle_ids()
  4    ;
  5    procedure reset_vehicleids
  6    is
  7    begin
  8      g_vehicle_ids.delete;
  9    end reset_vehicleids
 10    ;
 11    procedure store_vehicleid (p_vehicle_id in vehicles.id%type)
 12    is
 13    begin
 14      g_vehicle_ids.extend;
 15      g_vehicle_ids(g_vehicle_ids.count) := p_vehicle_id;
 16    end store_vehicleid
 17    ;
 18    procedure adjust_vehicle_last_allocation
 19    is
 20    begin
 21      update vehicles v
 22         set ( v.lastallocationusername
 23             , v.lastallocationdate
 24             , v.lastallocationid
 25             ) =
 26             ( select max(a.username) keep (dense_rank last order by a.mydate)
 27                    , max(a.mydate)
 28                    , max(a.id) keep (dense_rank last order by a.mydate)
 29                 from allocations a
 30                where a.vehicleid = v.id
 31             )
 32       where v.id in (select column_value from table(cast(g_vehicle_ids as t_vehicle_ids)))
 33      ;
 34    end adjust_vehicle_last_allocation
 35    ;
 36  end allocations_mutating_table;
 37  /

Package body created.
```

Then 3 database triggers to move the update code from the row level to statement level, thus circumventing the mutating table error:

```
SQL> create trigger allocations_bsiud
  2    before insert or update or delete on allocations
  3  begin
  4    allocations_mutating_table.reset_vehicleids;
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create trigger allocations_ariud
  2    after insert or update or delete on allocations
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    allocations_mutating_table.store_vehicleid(nvl(:new.vehicleid,:old.vehicleid));
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create trigger allocations_asiud
  2    after insert or update or delete on allocations
  3  begin
  4    allocations_mutating_table.adjust_vehicle_last_allocation;
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.
```

And a little test to verify that it works in a single user environment:

```
SQL> select * from vehicles
  2  /

        ID REGISTRATIONNUMBER LA LASTALLOCATIONDATE  LASTALLOCATIONID
---------- ------------------ -- ------------------- ----------------
         1                  1 Me 13-05-2010 14:03:43                2
         2                  2 Me 14-05-2010 14:03:43                3

2 rows selected.

SQL> insert into allocations values (4, 1, 'Me', sysdate)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> select * from vehicles
  2  /

        ID REGISTRATIONNUMBER LA LASTALLOCATIONDATE  LASTALLOCATIONID
---------- ------------------ -- ------------------- ----------------
         1                  1 Me 14-05-2010 14:03:43                4
         2                  2 Me 14-05-2010 14:03:43                3

2 rows selected.

SQL> update allocations
  2     set mydate = mydate - 2
  3   where id = 4
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from vehicles
  2  /

        ID REGISTRATIONNUMBER LA LASTALLOCATIONDATE  LASTALLOCATIONID
---------- ------------------ -- ------------------- ----------------
         1                  1 Me 13-05-2010 14:03:43                2
         2                  2 Me 14-05-2010 14:03:43                3

2 rows selected.

SQL> delete allocations
  2   where id in (2,4)
  3  /

2 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from vehicles
  2  /

        ID REGISTRATIONNUMBER LA LASTALLOCATIONDATE  LASTALLOCATIONID
---------- ------------------ -- ------------------- ----------------
         1                  1 Me 12-05-2010 14:03:43                1
         2                  2 Me 14-05-2010 14:03:43                3

2 rows selected.
```

Now all you have to do is add some serialization to make it work 100% in a multi user environment. But hopefully the example was scary enough as it is.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thanks for huge answer. I won't use packages. I will use global temporary table. It is much easier. It is still nice to see some package use and `keep (dense_rank last`, which is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The current setup requires you to use a trigger on the ALLOCATIONS table to maintain the poor decision choice.  That said, use:

```
UPDATE VEHICLE
   SET (LastAllocationUserName, LastAllocationDate, LastAllocationId) =
       (SELECT a.username,
               a.date,
               a.id
          FROM ALLOCATIONS a
          JOIN (SELECT b.vehicleid, 
                       MAX(b.date) AS max_date
                  FROM ALLOCATIONS b
              GROUP BY b.vehicleid) x ON x.vehicleid = a.vehicleid
                                     AND x.max_date = a.date
         WHERE a.vehicleid = VEHICLE.id)
```

This would be better served by removing the offending columns from the VEHICLE table, and using a view to provide the latest allocation information.

Answer (score 2):

From a design point of view, I'd prefer to have the three fields actively maintained on the Vehicle table, with the 'Allocations' populated as a history table (possibly by a trigger). A lot easier to push an update on a parent table down to an insert on a child than the other way around.

Comment: +1: Good point about `ALLOCATIONS` serving as a history/audit table.

Comment: That is not really the case here. In fact, there are much more fields in these tables and historical entries have to be edited. Vehicles also don't have all fields, that are in Allocations table. My question is not about database desin, but sql query. Tables are not modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to "update" using another table in Oracle is to use MERGE.

```
MERGE INTO vehicle v
USING (
  -- subquery to get info you need
) s ON (v.id = s.vehicleId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
  username = s.username 
  ...
```

http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Comment: Oracle 9i doesn't work well with MERGE. I want to update when it is matched or not matched. When it is not matched, values should be NULL. It doesn't work in 9i.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the Update inside the Trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER ALLOCATION_I
AFTER INSERT ON ALLOCATION
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
Begin

UPDATE Vehicle 
 set LastAllocationUserName = :NEW.Username 
 ,LastAllocationDate = :NEW.date 
 ,LastAllocationId = :NEW.id 
WHERE Id = :NEW.VehicleId;

END;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE VEHICLE V
   SET (LastAllocationId, LastAllocationDate, LastAllocationUserName) =
   (SELECT a.id
           ,a.date
           ,a.username
      FROM ALLOCATIONS a
      where a.VehicleId = V.id
        and a.date = ( select max(Last_a.date) from ALLOCATIONS Last_a
                       where Last_a.VehicleId = V.id )
    )
```

You're right. A View with a history table is slow. There is no such thing as a fast "join to last record". The trigger is the best solution.
If you can, use PL to populate the first time. It's easier to understand and mantain.

```
DECLARE
   Last_date DATE;
   Last_User Varchar2(100);
   Last_ID number;
Begin
FOR V IN ( Select * from VEHICLE )
LOOP
   select max(date) into Last_date 
   from ALLOCATIONS Last_a
   where Last_a.VehicleId = V.id;

   IF Last_date is NULL then 
      Last_User := NULL;
      Last_ID := NULL;
   else
      select Id,UserName into Last_id, Last_user
      from ALLOCATIONS Last_a
      where Last_a.VehicleId = V.id
      and Last_a.date = Last_date;
   END IF;

   UPDATE Vehicle 
     set LastAllocationUserName = Last_User
         ,LastAllocationDate = Last_date
         ,LastAllocationId Last_id
   Where id = V.id;

END LOOP;
End;
```

Warning: written here, not tested.

Comment: -1 for every sentence written here, and for the horribly inefficient code

Comment: If it is to be run once, it should be clear no efficient.
Anyway, where's your efficient solution?

Comment: @Lucio M. Tato: It is not to run once, but to run frequently in trigger on Allocations tables. I am not even sure if your query will even work, because there is nested subquery to get maximum date, which used V alias and Oracle doesn't allow this, AFAIK. I'll check it at home. This is why I asked this question. Oracle has some limitations that make this kind of query look very ugly.

Comment: @LukLed: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the Allocation table's trigger there will be a simple update.

   UPDATE Vehicle set LastAllocationUserName = :NEW.Username 
   , LastAllocationDate = :NEW.date
   , LastAllocationId = :NEW.id
   where Id = :NEW.VehicleId;

assuming the allocations are inserted chronologically.

Comment: No, it will not. Allocations don't have to be inserted chronologically. I also don't want to make one update for every row in the table. I want to gather VehicleId's (in for each before trigger) first and then update appropriate vehicles (in after trigger).

Comment: Ok. Strange conditions. Can't you sort the rows to insert by date?
It's a bulk insert?
The PL will do. To enhance performance you should use a cursor and WHERE CURRENT OF instead of the FOR LOOP. The best solution will be to have the trigger and the rows inserted chronologically (normal situation).

Comment: To gather ID's you can use a PACKAGE and a global package variable (TABLE OF) or you can use a global temporary table (insert in before trigger for each row, use in after insert trigger). Nasty solutions. But if you can't modify the tables nor the application...

Comment: I use global temporary table. My question is only about UPDATE statement. It will be trigger, it will use global temporary table. I just wanted to know the easiest solution to write SQL UPDATE. As I wrote, with SQL Server it would be UPDATE FROM. Oracle doesn't support this construction.

Comment: Add your SQL-Server code to the question for clarification.
ORACLE support tuples, check the previous responses: UPDATE TBL set (a,b,c) = (Select d, e, f FROM...)